# How to update the record in an azure function triggered by a webhook?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, azure-functions, webhooks, microsoft-dynamics

I have an Azure function triggered post creation of a record in Dynamics 365 CE. The azure function and Dynamics 365 CE are integrated by a Webhook registered via the Plugin Registration.

What is the best way to update some data fields inside the record in RemoteExecutionContext .

Do I connect to Dynamics again or I can update as part of the Dynamics pipeline?

I have tried the `.InputParameters["Target"].Id` but upon updating with a new HttpClient I am getting a record not found error, whereas the webhook is in Post.

```
JObject Obj1 = new JObject();
Obj1.Add(STATE, 1);
Obj1.Add(STATUS, 123);
obj1.Add(ERROR_MESSAGE, "Update");

HttpRequestMessage updateApiRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), $"{d365Client.BaseAddress}new_customeentity1({targetEntity.Id.ToString()})");
updateApiRequest.Content = new StringContent(obj1.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage updateResposne = await d365Client.SendAsync(updateApiRequest );
```

What's the best way to achieve a similar integration?
How can I update the record within the pipeline without getting the Record Not Found error?

Comment: Are you doing anything else in this Azure function through this webhook? If not simply do all this in plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would check two things for solving this particular "record not found" issue:

1. Try to register the step in "Asynchronous" mode if it's registered as "Synchronous" [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-webhooks#register-a-step-for-a-webhook)
2. Verify the code sample & important points explained in [this blog](https://www.akaes.com/blog/writing-microsoft-dynamics-365-plug-ins-in-azure-functions/). Basically to avoid **sandbox limitations** and **External Integration** purpose only we go for Azure functions/webhooks

So, if you are not doing anything else other than this simple update back to CRM record, then complete the `service.Update` in post-create plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks for a response Arun. I am already thinking about 1 (moving to async webhook).

Comment: @user3687899 let us know how it goes

Comment: What do you mean by service.Update? Is it the SDK Organisation Service Update entity object?

Comment: @user3687899 pls refer: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/260229

Comment: Yes, a slight change to the design.

Changing the pipeline to async.
Confirmation on that Azure Function will need a dedicated connection to D365.

Comment: @user3687899 glad that you are able to sort it. Pls add your answer & close this question. Also you can upvote my answer if it was helpful :)